# Can we use Microsoft TensorFlow as regular TensorFlow?

Tags: c#, .net, tensorflow

Most of the tutorials/guides I found on Microsoft ML are for sentiment analysis or image classification. For my project I need to use TensorFlow functions like it can be with Python. As TensorFlow nuget package is available I'm wondering if this can be used as original TensorFlow alternative. Asking reason of this question here is - I could not find a guide or documentation on this.

I can import TensorFlow after getting it from nuget package manager. But I can't access its regular methods or constants like it can be with Python.

The following code is valid:

```
using System;
using Tensorflow;

namespace TF_Tests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = TensorInfo.Descriptor;

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World! "+a);
        }
    }
}
```

TensorFlow can be imported, but how can I use it in a regular way? For example:

```
c = tf.strings.unicode_split(a, 'UTF-8').to_list() //how to access such method or atleast declare a constant?

print(c[0].__len__())

for i in c[0]:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you just need to split strings, C# has a `string.Split` method.

As for TensorFlow, Microsoft.TensorFlow includes https://github.com/SciSharp/TensorFlow.NET , which you should be able to use as the regular TensorFlow, though your mileage may vary as algorithms or even ops implementations can be incomplete without warning (see e.g. https://github.com/SciSharp/TensorFlow.NET/blob/master/src/TensorFlowNET.Core/Training/GradientDescentOptimizer.cs ).

Alternatively, there are

- [TensorFlowSharp](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp), which is no longer maintained, but has no surprises like missing parts
- [Gradient](https://losttech.software/gradient.html), which requires a commercial license if used for profit in a sufficiently large company.

Comment: Thank you for answering. string.split is not focus it is just an example.  So I assume it is not possible at this moment with default MS TF from nuget package manager. We need to use other available libraries.